# When cnosdb starts normally, an error message appears: MetaClientErr

Tags: cnosdb

When cnosdb starts normally, an error message appears: MetaClientErr

```
2023-10-25T10:17:38.352353000+08:00  INFO meta::model::meta_admin: watch response wrong Err(MetaClientErr { msg: "NetworkError: reqwest::error::Error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8901/watch): connection closed before message completed source: connection closed before message completed" })
```

version: cnosdb 2.3.3, revision d86358a6fc813f4b83b36f0005448e7140a2d4e0

./target/release/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_8902.toml -M singleton

Answer (score 0):

This question is same as [\w oceanic_station.txt write fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382930/w-oceanic-station-txt-write-fail).

You can try a reboot, or try it on the latest version, the issue should have been fixed