# \w oceanic_station.txt write fail

Tags: cnosdb

\w oceanic_station.txt write fail.
cnosdb-cli in system path
version: cnosdb 2.3.3, revision d86358a6fc813f4b83b36f0005448e7140a2d4e0

```
public ❯ \d
Query took 0.003 seconds.
public ❯ \w oceanic_station.txt
Query took 0.419 seconds.
public ❯ \d
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| air        |
| wind       |
+------------+
Query took 0.014 seconds.
public ❯ \d
Query took 0.043 seconds.
public ❯ \w oceanic_station.txt
Query took 0.372 seconds.
public ❯ \d
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| air        |
+------------+
Query took 0.010 seconds.
```

```
2023-10-24T20:04:07.147874000+08:00 DEBUG coordinator::writer: write data to local 1001(3) Err(Meta { source: MetaClientErr { msg: "NetworkError: reqwest::error::Error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8901/read): connection closed before message completed source: connection closed before message completed" } })
2023-10-24T20:04:07.148068000+08:00 DEBUG coordinator::writer: Parallel write points on vnode over, start at: Instant { tv_sec: 891340, tv_nsec: 230825166 }, elapsed: 48 millis, result: Err(Meta { source: MetaClientErr { msg: "NetworkError: reqwest::error::Error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8901/read): connection closed before message completed source: connection closed before message completed" } })
2023-10-24T20:04:07.834871000+08:00 DEBUG meta::store::state_machine: meta process write command ReportNodeMetrics("cluster_xxx", NodeMetrics { id: 1001, disk_free: 91437920256, time: 1698149047, status: Healthy })
2023-10-24T20:04:07.835068000+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /data_version :13
2023-10-24T20:04:07.835092000+08:00  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":91437920256,"time":1698149047,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-10-24T20:04:08.535215000+08:00 DEBUG cnosdb::http::http_service: Receive http sql request, header: Header { accept: Some("application/table"), authorization: "Basic cm9vdDo=", private_key: None }, param: SqlParam { tenant: Some("cnosdb"), db: Some("public"), chunked: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None }
2023-10-24T20:04:08.535358000+08:00 DEBUG cnosdb::http::http_service: prepare to execute: "SHOW TABLES"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the meta process hanging？
You can try a reboot, or try it on the latest version, the issue should have been fixed